# What purpose does the Challenge Token really serve in Vtiger Web Services?

Tags: web-services, vtiger

I am calling VTiger (6.4) webservices from a multi-threaded Java application. Each time I need to call a web service, I start with getting a Challenge Token from VT, then Login and finally perform my Query.

In reviewing the VT Web Services code, it seems that the above is not "thread safe" since the token obtained by one thread will be overwritten in VT's database by the token obtained in the second thread. If the Java application happened to reverse the execution order of threads when the VT Login web service is called one of those calls would fail as having in incorrect token.

I realize that I could cache the token within my app...but that means implementing mutex locking of shared storage, etc.

So, my question is: Does the Challenge Token really add much security to VTiger's web services? Or, could it be bypassed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token prevents your session from being stolen. An alternative to that token would be using your accessKey in every call, but Vtiger Webservices were not built that way.

It certainly can be bypassed if you modify the authentication code in vtiger's base code. At least you would need to modify two files

```
vtiger_root/include/Webservices/AuthToken.php
```

and

```
vtiger_root/include/Webservices/Login.php
```

I think you should share a single token across threads. Maybe use a singleton to implement the session establishment.

Comment: Thanks Ruben. That's helpful. We'd like to use VTiger as an identify provider to implement SSO across a couple applications (Java-based web app & a wordpress support site). The java app, in particular, can be scaled across multiple servers. So, a singleton for session establishment isnt' quite so straightforward.

Comment: Sounds complex. As for security, I'm not sure if removing the token would be less secure. Would be interesting to hear how you end up solving this.

Comment: For now, I'm going to use it 'as is' since chance of an actual collision is low. As a long term fix: Switch my web service to 'preLogin' so it doesn't require the challenge/login be performed. Then, similar to what Amazon S3 does: Add an 'expires time' value as an additional request param. Sign the entire contents of the request using hmac & the AccessKey. Send the sign along with the request. On the server, re-compute the sign using the AccessKey. If the sign is correct (request hasn't been tampered with) AND expires time hasn't arrived yet, perform the request. Also makes it less "chatty"